Passport Validity Requirements
I have regular Pakistani Passport. I am flying from Los Angeles to Lahore in December and I have a layover of 5 hours in Jeddah and I’ll not leave the airport. My passport is expiring in January and still should I have passport valid for 6 months? Airline is Saudi Airlines and same airline throughout the journey.

Is it a single ticket with a connection?

Yes. It is single ticket with Saudi Airlines with a layover of 5 hours in Jeddah.

I don't think there are any requirements on passport validity from Saudi Arabia for airside transit purposes, but I haven't double-checked. Enter your details in to the IATA Travel Centre and TravelDoc, that will give you the same information airlines use.
